# Change user agent in QWebEngineView

Tags: qt, qwebview, qtwebengine

How to change the user agent in `QWebEngineView`?
I know that for `QWebView` there is a way to do this but I didn't find the solution for the `QWebEngineView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While constructing [QWebEnginePage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html) as one of the arguments you may specify [QWebEngineProfile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html).

QWebEngineProfile - it is a class which contains different settings for your profile which can be shared between web pages.

For setting user agent you will need to use:

```
void QWebEngineProfile::setHttpUserAgent(const QString & userAgent)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#setHttpUserAgent

QWebEngineProfile is available since Qt 5.5.